# Get all the child values in Firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get all the values inside parent without having the child keys. How can i retrieve them in android?

[image: See This Image - Example]

In this image "BewafaShayari" is the parent and i want all the children values in a string.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `ChildEventListener` like this:

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String item = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
        items.add(item);
    }
...
```

Comment: Your code works but when i display the items in TextView the output for my input comes in this format `[null, hdsfj dshaj., dfsjka., ankush., null, sdsdj`but i want only want the values corresponding to the key ie `hdsfj dshaj., dfsjka, ankush, sdsdj` how can i get that?

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("BewafaShayari");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String s1 = (String) dataSnapshot.child("1").getValue();
        String s2 = (String) dataSnapshot.child("2").getValue();
        String s3 = (String) dataSnapshot.child("3").getValue();
        String s5 = (String) dataSnapshot.child("5").getValue();

        String finalString = s1 + s2 + s3 + s5;
        Log.d("TAG", finalString);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Hope it helps.